# I have a problem about connect 3g shield to raspberrypi

Tags: usb, gps, gsm

```
import serial

portwrite = "/dev/ttyUSB2"
port = "/dev/ttyUSB1"

def parseGPS(data):
    print "raw:", data #prints raw data
    if data[0:6] == "$GPRMC":
        sdata = data.split(",")
        if sdata[2] == 'V':
             print "no satellite data available"
             return
        print "-----Parsing GPRMC-----"
        time = sdata[1][0:2] + ":" + sdata[1][2:4] + ":" + sdata[1][4:6]
        lat = decode(sdata[3]) #latitude
        dirLat = sdata[4]      #latitude direction N/S
        lon = decode(sdata[5]) #longitute
        dirLon = sdata[6]      #longitude direction E/W
        speed = sdata[7]       #Speed in knots
        trCourse = sdata[8]    #True course
        date = sdata[9][0:2] + "/" + sdata[9][2:4] + "/" + sdata[9][4:6]
            #date
        variation = sdata[10]  #variation
        degreeChecksum = sdata[12]
        dc = degreeChecksum.split("*")
        degree = dc[0]        #degree
        checksum = dc[1]      #checksum
        print "time : %s, latitude : %s(%s), longitude : %s(%s), speed : %s, True Course : %s, Date : %s, Magnetic Variation : %s(%s),Checksum : %s "%    (time,lat,dirLat,lon,dirLon,speed,trCourse,date,variation,degree,checks$
    else:
        print "Printed data is ",data[0:6]
def decode(coord):
    #Converts DDDMM.MMMMM -> DD deg MM.MMMMM min
    x = coord.split(".")
    head = x[0]
    tail = x[1]
    deg = head[0:-2]
    min = head[-2:]
    return deg + " deg " + min + "." + tail + " min"

print "Connecting port"
serw = serial.Serial(portwrite, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1)
serw.write('AT+QGPS=1\r')
serw.close()
sleep(0.5)

print "Receiving GPS data"
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0.5)
while True:
   data = ser.readline()
   parseGPS(data)
```

result from code

```
Connecting port 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "gpstest.py", line 41, in <module> 
      serw = serial.Serial(portwrite, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 1) 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 236, in __init__ 
      self.open() 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 286, in open 
      self._update_dtr_state() 
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 612, in _update_dtr_state 
      fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCMBIS, TIOCM_DTR_str) 
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: Are you sure about the ports you use ? `/dev/ttyUSB1` and `/dev/ttyUSB2` ? Do they appear when you type `ls -la /dev/tty*`

Comment: I have this result.
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  0 Feb 28 00:25 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  1 Feb 28 00:25 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  2 Feb 28 00:25 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188,  3 Feb 28 00:25 /dev/ttyUSB3

Comment: `could not open port /dev/ttyUSB2: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB2'` Thats the error! And with the few details you have posted, it's a guessing game!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, and setting both rtscts and dsrdtr to True solved it for me, try:

```
print "Connecting port"
serw = serial.Serial(portwrite, baudrate=115200, timeout=1, dsrdtr=True, rtscts=True)
serw.write('AT+QGPS=1\r')
```

and:

```
print "Receiving GPS data"
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200, timeout=0.5, dsrdtr=True, rtscts=True)
```